# Java GSON not deserializing all fields, even when they are of same type

Tags: java, json, gson, deserialization, json-deserialization

I have the classes:

```java
public class SentPlayer {
    final String uuid;
    final String playerName;
    final String universeUuid;
/* some get methods and constructors */
}
```

```java
public class PlayerMsg {
    public final SentPlayer player;
    public final String msg;
/* constructors and such */
}
```

Then I have this JSON coming in from a api:

```json
{
    "player": {
        "uuid": "",
        "playerName": "Rushmore75",
        "universeUuid": "9dae671e-91ed-440e722c12"
    },
    "msg": "1234"
}
```

However when I go to deserialize said json into the `PlayerMsg` class all the fields except `"playerName"` deserialize, and `playerName` is just `null` instead of `"Rushmore75"`. I am using the default GSON configuration with "serializeNulls" enabled. Using gson 2.10

Comment: Just a thought could you try to use the @SerializedName annotation from Gson to map the JSON field to the correct field in the SentPlayer class like below

Comment: `@SerializedName("playerName")
    final String name;`

Comment: I tried the response below, where all 3 fields have the annotation above it, or with just the annotation on playerName, and that didn't work. Even with changing the actual variable's name, to make sure it isn't some masking issue or something. So it is aware of the annotation, just not de serializing it.

Comment: let me mock the issue locally and see

Comment: What does your **full** class look like?

Comment: @M. Deinum not much more than what's there. I'm getting the data from a http stream, building it into a string, trying to create the object, then turning it back into json to test if it was build correctly.

Comment: @Rushmore75, please nonetheless provide a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). That would make it way easier for others to reproduce this issue. And also, while creating the minimal example maybe you yourself find the underlying cause for the issue.

Comment: There is more and we need to see it as that is probably part of your problem. Hence the request for the full classes.

Answer (score 0):

*Edited
I could not see how your request is being POSTED, and the source code is different from ur questions' implementation, but using the below code and controller, it should work, this is **just a sample** you could ammend where neccesary:

```
  public class SentPlayer {
    @SerializedName("uuid")
    private String uuid;
    @SerializedName("playerName")
    private String playerName;
    @SerializedName("universeUuid")
    private String universeUuid;
    
public SentPlayer(String uuid, String playerName, String universeUuid) {
    this.uuid = uuid;
    this.playerName = playerName;
    this.universeUuid = universeUuid;
}

// getters and setters
public String getUuid() {
    return uuid;
}

public void setUuid(String uuid) {
    this.uuid = uuid;
}

public String getPlayerName() {
    return playerName;
}

public void setPlayerName(String playerName) {
    this.playerName = playerName;
}

public String getUniverseUuid() {
    return universeUuid;
}

public void setUniverseUuid(String universeUuid) {
    this.universeUuid = universeUuid;
}
}

public class PlayerMsg {
    public SentPlayer player;
    public String msg; 
}

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/playerMsg")
public class PlayerMsgController {
    @PostMapping
    public ResponseEntity<String> createPlayerMsg(@RequestBody String jsonInput) {
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        PlayerMsg playerMsg = gson.fromJson(jsonInput, PlayerMsg.class);

        // Perform any necessary processing with playerMsg here...

        return ResponseEntity.ok("Player message created.");
    }
}
```

Comment: Nope, still not deserializing it.

Comment: @Rushmore75 I've edited the answers, can try again

Comment: @Rushmore75 reedited, not sure if u get notified when i edited the answers

Comment: still no, GSON uses reflection to go thru the class to find the fields IIRC, this is how it can find private, final, etc, to (de)serialize objects. I tested it anyways just to be sure but still no luck.

Also since it was deserializing adjacent fields that were also "default final" it couldn't have been that

Comment: "@JsonUnwrapped" is a Jackson feature, whereas I'm using GSON. But it looks like that wouldn't be the ticket either, it looks like that just flattens Java objects when going to JSON ( If I'm reading it correctly )

Comment: Okay thanks for the feedback, but could i have a look / more info on ur API, annotations etc.. "I am using the default GSON configuration with "serializeNulls" enabled"

Comment: yeah totally! [here's](https://github.com/Rushmore75/RushmoreTweaks) the repo, with [this](https://github.com/Rushmore75/RushmoreTweaks/blob/master/src/main/java/com/basemod/base/util/PlayerMsg.java) being our topic. It's getting called in [here](https://github.com/Rushmore75/RushmoreTweaks/blob/master/src/main/java/com/basemod/base/event/DiscordRP.java) at 240ish. The server it's talking to is [this](https://github.com/Rushmore75/ftbu-drp-ws). But the main idea of that is just to provide a REST API

Comment: I've updated answers for references.

Comment: It's not receiving a post request to get the data, It's subscribing to a different application's stream via http get

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me

Main.java

```java
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String json = "{\"player\":{\"uuid\":\"\",\"playername\":\"Rushmore75\",\"universeUuid\":\"9dae671e-91ed-440e722c12\"},\"msg\":\"1234\"}";

        Gson gson = new Gson();
        PlayerMsg playerMsg = gson.fromJson(json, PlayerMsg.class);

        System.out.println(playerMsg.getPlayer().getPlayerName());
    }
}
```

PlayerMsg.java

```java
public class PlayerMsg {
    private final SentPlayer player;
    private final String msg;

    public PlayerMsg(SentPlayer player, String msg) {
        this.player = player;
        this.msg = msg;
    }

    public SentPlayer getPlayer() {
        return player;
    }

    public String getMsg() {
        return msg;
    }
}
```

SentPlayer.java

```java
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;
public class SentPlayer {
    private final String uuid;
    @SerializedName("playername")
    private final String playerName;
    private final String universeUuid;

    public SentPlayer(String uuid, String playerName, String universeUuid) {
        this.uuid = uuid;
        this.playerName = playerName;
        this.universeUuid = universeUuid;
    }

    public String getUuid() {
        return uuid;
    }

    public String getPlayerName() {
        return playerName;
    }

    public String getUniverseUuid() {
        return universeUuid;
    }
}
```

`OUTPUT: Rushmore75`

Comment: based on my comment i tried to mock it, worked as expected